# Active Directory Check With Login

Tags: authentication, active-directory, joomla2.5

I've created a login control for my company's site and want it to check the user names against the already created active directory on my server(some 700 names) I have the LDAP connection string but for the life of me I can't figure out how I should be using it(noobie problem I'm sure). Looking for a point in the right direction before I start bashing holes in the wall. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://ourlife01.blogspot.de/2012/03/connect-to-ad-using-joomla-25.html

Is this what you are looking for?